# How to update "sum" field on editing existing fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Items controller with num1 num2 and sum field. I want to update the sum field in the database at the time of editing num1 or num2 from edit.html.erb. For calculating the sum field at the time of user input, I am already using callback

```
before_create :set_sum_value

private
def set_sum_value
  self.sum = (self.num1 + self.num2)
  true
end
```

What callback should I use at the time of updating num1 , num 2 so that sum is automatically calculated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put this code in your model:

```
   after_validation :set_sum_value

   def set_sum_value
      self.sum = num1 + num2
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a callback, you don't need it. Override the setter for `num1` and `num2` so that each time you change the value, the sum is automatically updated.

```
class Model

  def num1=(value)
    update_sum
    write_attribute(:num1, value)
  end

  def num2=(value)
    update_sum
    write_attribute(:num2, value)
  end

  private

  def update_sum
    self.sum = num1.to_i + num2.to_i
  end

end
```

Using a callback here is not the appropriate choice.

- The callback is executed only at the time the creation happens. Therefore if you change `num1` or `num2` and you call `.sum`, a wrong value will be returned.
- The callback is not executed when the object is updated
- Callbacks in ActiveRecord are abused

Also note, in `update_sum` I forced bot num values to integer. In fact, you may set a nil value to `num1` that will result in a crash when you try to compute the sum, unless you ensure `nil` is converted to 0.